# CASE and CONCAT in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a scenario where there are 2 tables.

Table 1:

[image]

Table 2:

[image]

So, the CID is the Client ID and PID is the Parent ID. There are 4 conditions and I have made CIDs each one to obey each condition:

1. If table1 Client ID, Parent ID and SSC are same and there is no End date on Table 2, the concatenate the data of table 1 and table 2
2. If table1 Client ID, Parent ID and SSC are same and there is no end date for that CID on both the table then display Data of table 1
3. If table1 Client ID, Parent ID and SSC are same and there is no end date for that CID in table 1 but there is an end date for that CID in table 2 then concatenate Data of both the tables
4. If table1 Client ID, SSC are same but PID is different, then show the data in two separate lines.

Below is the desired output:

[image]

Rextester link:

https://rextester.com/GBY12899

I am still working on my trial code and will post it soon. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a contradiction between your conditions and the desired output:

> If table1 Client ID, Parent ID and SSC are same and there is no end
>   date for that CID on both the table then display Data of table 1

so in the row `1003/1116` the `ssc` value should be `OR20121005`, right?
I got this as a solution, based on the data in the rextester link:

```
select 
 t1.CID CID, t1.PID PID,
 case 
   when (t1.End_Date is null) and (t2.End_Date is null) then t1.Data 
   when (t1.End_Date is null) or (t2.End_Date is null) then t1.Data + ' ' + t2.Data
 end SSC
from #table1 t1 inner join #table2 t2 on t1.CID = t2.CID and t1.SSC = t2.SSC and t1.PID = t2.PID
union
select t1.CID, t1.PID, t1.Data SSC 
from #table1 t1 
where exists (select 1 from #table2 t2 where t1.CID = t2.CID and t1.SSC = t2.SSC and t1.PID <> t2.PID)
union
select t2.CID, t2.PID, t2.Data SSC 
from #table2 t2 
where exists (select 1 from #table1 t1 where t1.CID = t2.CID and t1.SSC = t2.SSC and t1.PID <> t2.PID)
```

See the [demo](https://rextester.com/DWMBL45377)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution using a CTE.

```
;with dataset as(
select 
    t1.* 
    ,case when (t1.End_date is null and t2.End_date is null) then t1.data
        when  (t2.End_date is null or t1.End_date is null) then t1.data + ' - ' + t2.data 
        else null 
    end AS DataConditions


from #table1 t1
    left join #table2 t2    on t1.CID = t2.CID
                                AND t1.PID = t2.PID
                                AND t1.SSC = t2.SSC

union all

select 
    t2.*
    ,case when (t1.End_date is null and t2.End_date is null) then t1.data
        when  (t2.End_date is null or t1.End_date is null) then t1.data + ' - ' + t2.data 
        else null 
    end

from #table2 t2
    left join #table1 t1    on t1.CID = t2.CID
                                AND t1.PID = t2.PID
                                AND t1.SSC = t2.SSC

WHERE t1.PID IS NULL
)

select
    CID, PID, Coalesce(DataConditions, dataset.Data) AS SSC
from dataset
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=1949a1f1f7c3e28562b93bf697d129e4)

Answer (score 1):

Hi very unfortunately your questions has errors 1st of all in all 4 questions this part is meaningless "If table1 Client ID, Parent ID and SSC are same" because they are IDs so they are the same when Join is used upon it.

I tried to change your questions and attempted to solve it

The following 2 questions I have answered but to be honest its just a matter of adding columns to the CONCAT list and condition  otherwise you can use this query to get your answers

Query CASES: 1_If there is EndDate in Table1 and no EndDate in Table 2, then concatenate Table1 SSC + Table1 StartDate + Table1 EndDate

2_If there is no EndDate on both tables then display Table1 SSC value + Table2 StartDate space value from Table2 Data column

```
SELECT T1.CID
,T1.PID
,CASE
    WHEN T1.EndDate IS NOT NULL AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') = '' THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T1.StartDate,T1.EndDate)
    WHEN ISNULL(T1.EndDate,'') =  '' AND ISNULL(T2.EndDate,'') =  ''  THEN CONCAT(T1.SSC, T2.StartDate, '  ', T2.Data)
ELSE NULL END AS SSC


FROM temp.dbo.TABLE1 AS T1
LEFT JOIN temp.dbo.TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.CID = T2.CID AND T1.PID = T2.PID AND T1.SSC = T2.SSC
```

It gives the following result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This produces the exact results that you're looking for, on your demo data.

```
select 
    t1.cid
    ,ot.pid
    ,ot.ssc 
from #table1 t1
outer apply (
    SELECT 
        t1.PID
        ,case when t2.pid <> t1.pid or (isnull(t1.end_date, t2.end_date) is null) then t1.data   -- rule 2 and part A of rule 4
            else concat(t1.data, '     ', t2.data)      -- rules 1 and 3
        end as SSC
    FROM #table2 t2
    where t2.cid = t1.cid
     and t2.ssc = t1.ssc

    union 

    -- this is to get the 2nd row for CID 1004 - part B of rule 4
    SELECT 
        t2.PID
        ,t2.data as SSC
    FROM #table2 t2
    where t2.cid = t1.cid
     and t2.ssc = t1.ssc
     and t2.pid <> t1.pid

) ot
```

However, you do not describe the relationship between the 2 tables, so I'm not sure if it will work on actual data - could there be more records for a CID + SSC combination in 1 table than what there is in the other?
For example, could Table2 look like this - added another row for CID 1004:

```
create table #table2(CID int,PID int,SSC varchar(5),Start_date varchar(30),End_date varchar(30), Data varchar(20))
insert #table2
values
(1001,  1333,   'OP','20111015',NULL,'OP20111015'),
(1002,  1245,   'OR','20131005',NULL,'OR20131005'),
(1003,  1116,   'OP','20131415',NULL,'OP2013141520131516'),
(1004,  1235,   'OP','20121015',NULL,'OP20121015'),
(1004,  1234,   'OP','20151015',NULL,'WHAT')
```